# SQLite in python does not update DB after commit command

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I wrote this script to update a SQL DB with sqlite in Python 2.7
As input in the function we have a ten elements list, that some elements can be None or not, I only want to update the not None elements.

The issue here, when the script runs it does not return any error, even I tried few "print "line xx"" to debug and check if the script goes through the if, Update, and commit commands. The result is always good but then the DB is not update.

*Note, in another function in the same program I read data from the same DB so I have good access to read the DB.

```
def update_coin(new_data):
    #data_coin is a 10 element list

    id = new_data[0]

    with con:

        cur = con.cursor()

        if new_data[3] is not None:
            cur.execute("UPDATE COIN_KM SET KM_NUM =? WHERE ID_KM = ?", (new_data[3], id))

        if new_data[4] is not None:
            cur.execute("UPDATE COIN_KM SET ID_NUMIS =? WHERE ID_KM = ?", (new_data[4], id))

        if new_data[5] is not None:
            cur.execute("UPDATE COIN_KM SET DDATE =? WHERE ID_KM = ?", (new_data[5], id))

        if new_data[7] is not None:
            cur.execute("UPDATE COIN_KM SET TITLE =? WHERE ID_KM = ?", (new_data[7], id))

        if new_data[8] is not None:
            cur.execute("UPDATE COIN_KM SET DESCRIPTION =? WHERE ID_KM = ?", (new_data[8], id))

        if new_data[10] is not None:
            cur.execute("UPDATE COIN_KM SET MATERIAL =? WHERE ID_KM = ?", (new_data[10], id))

        con.commit()
```

Anyone can figure out what is wrong here?? Earlier I had similar script and didnt have this issue.
*I work in a VM with Ubuntu, I change permissions to 777 to my DB and script.
*I run the script with terminal like root.

Comment: Can you give value in `new_data` ? then we can execute same program and see its working or not, please add full executable code,

Comment: @JohnSnow, could you please provide your imports?

Comment: What is shown by `print len(con.execute('SELECT * FROM Coin_km WHERE ID_km = ?', (id,)).fetchall())`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, you help me to figure out the issue!

In the inputs id = new_data[0] was always None. Now everything run good.